# ASIHTTPRequest: check if username/password is correct

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, passwords, asihttprequest

How can I check a webservice if the username/password is correct?

I don't want to transfer the whole response body. I only want to know if the username/password exists and is correct. Currently I'm sending a request to my webservice like this:

```
self.request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:urlObject];
[self.request setUsername:username];
[self.request setPassword:password];
[self.request addRequestHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
[self.request setDelegate:self];
[self.request startAsynchronous];
```

If I access the webservice with a browser and I insert a wrong password, I again get the authentication dialog displayed. I tried the same in Xcode and I get a status code = 200 if password was wrong. I thought I can do that with the status codes like 401 and so on. But that didn't worked, because I always get status code = 200. Do I have to change something on the serverside?

I'm using a REST webservice, which uses Restlet 2.0 as Java framework. [Docs](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/27-restlet/46-restlet/112-restlet.html)

Comment: It really depends on the webservice and its interface contract

Comment: Can you explain that in more detail? What are the possibilities?

Comment: How are you passing the username & password to the web service? Exactly what API is the web service using? Can you tell us what web service it is? There isn't really a "standard" way for REST web services to do username/password checking - if you're getting a 200 code, it's likely the body of the response contains the real answer.

Comment: Now the `requestFailed:` is called, if a username/password is wrong ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure exactly how your webservice works, but from the information given I think I can answer your question.

If you are getting 'requestFailed:' when the username and password is wrong, then you should be able to avoid downloading the response body by using:

```
[request setRequestMethod:@"HEAD"];
```